# Was trying to validate the Central Limit Theorem, the plot generated is a bit confusing

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

[Periodic gaps in the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44gk9.png)

Was implementing the proof to Central Limit Theorem

```
X = [0]*10000000
i = 100
for j in range(i):
    a = (np.random.randint(0, high = 4, size = 10000000 ))
    X = X+a
plt.hist(X, bins='auto')
plt.show()
# print (Counter(X))
```

Comment: Looks like a plotting artifact.  With your plot window open, grab the edge of the window and make it larger.  As you vary the size of the window, you'll see the thin vertical lines appear and disappear.

Comment: I thought of that but as the gaps looked periodic, I thought it was due to the code.

Comment: It is a glitch in the `hist` plot.  `matplotlib` doesn't always do a great job of rasterizing thin vertical lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a plotting artifact of the `hist` command.  With the plot window open, change the size of the window.  You'll see the thin vertical bars appear and disappear.

If I change the `hist` command to

```
plt.hist(X, bins=np.arange(X.min()-1, X.max()+2)
```

I get

[image: histogram]

Answer (score 0):

The automatic binning of `plt.hist` interacts with `randint` to cause this artifact. Use `np.random.random` to overcome this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array([0]*10000000)
i = 100
for j in range(i):
    a = np.random.random(10000000) * 4 # multiplying by 4 to simulate high=4 in OP's code
    X = X+a
plt.hist(X, bins='auto')
plt.show()
```

Update: As @Warren mentions, the issue was the automatic binning behavior of `plt.hist`. By picking numbers uniformly instead of integers, this issue is made to disappear. If you must use randint, his solution works.

[image]

Comment: This code *does* nicely demonstrate the central limit theorem, but using integers instead of uniform floats was not the real cause of the problem in the question.